# Flask data being pulled through an API get refreshed everytime someone accesses the site?

Tags: python, api, flask

I'm a Data Analyst so I'm new to Flask and web dev but I'm building my own site for reports and I'm curious how often the data being pulled from an API is refreshed.

Right now, I have a python script that pulls data from an API and does some cleansing and formatting. I am importing the data frames from the script into my Flask app then rendering a template that uses the 'to_html' function to convert my pandas data frame into HTML.

My question is every time someone views the table, does the data get pulled thru the API again and refreshed or is it gonna stay static?

Any insight will be much appreciated!

Comment: it depends on the provider ... for example most stock market api's refresh every 15 minutes ... id imagine a geolocation api would be pretty static... so this is lacking soime info if you want an actual answer...

Comment: I meant on my site when would it update, like if the API just refreshed would my site be updated immediately if I reloaded it?

Comment: By default, web-service based on Flask pulls data from db or whatever source and process it every time when URL is requested. But it's really hard question to answer without viewing the code.

Comment: I think you are missing some pieces to the puzzle ... once a table is rendered it will stay static until it is reloaded via refresh or javascript reload ... if you have an api, the default behaviour is to fetch the data every time the page is refreshed from the datasource... you can use something like memcached to only refresh the data every 15 minutes or something

Comment: That answers my question, thanks everybody!